# move initial letter to the end of the word and add arg while punctuation to be in the end of word

Tags: python

I need to take the initial letter of every word, moving it to the end of the word and adding 'arg'. For such I tried the following way

```
def pirate(str):
  list_str = str.split(' ')
  print(list_str)
  new_str = ''
  for lstr in list_str:
    first_element = lstr[0]
    second_element = lstr[1:]
    new_str += second_element + first_element + 'arg' + ' '
  return new_str
print(pirate('Hello! how are, you!!'))
```

The expected output is: elloHarg! owharg reaarg, ouyarg!!

However, I am getting following output: ello!Harg owharg re,aarg ou!!yarg

How can I make it work the following usecase?

Punctuations should remain at the end of the word even after translation. Assume Punctuations wont appear after than end of the word. Punctuations to be considered are .,:;?! There could be multiple punctuations present (e.g yes!!)

Comment: Is this an assignment? Can you use (standard) librairies?

Comment: Honestly, this is an assignment and I have only 5 minute left. I think we can use it but I am not quite sure

Comment: If this is an assignment probably not, you should define a list of letters (ABCD...) and use that to split your words in the letter and punctuation parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short and efficient solution using a regex:

```
import re
re.sub(r'(\w)(\w+)', r'\2\1arg', 'Hello! how are, you!!')
```

This is literally: replace each single letter followed by more letters by the more letters first, then the single letter and 'arg'

Output:

```
'elloHarg! owharg reaarg, ouyarg!!'
```

As a function:

```
def pirate(s):
    return re.sub(r'(\w)(\w+)', r'\2\1arg', s)
```